# Xamarin XAML ResourceDictionary causes Null Reference ex

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, prism, resourcedictionary

Wanting to add a style to my labels in XAML I have stumbled upon the [Xamarin Developer Guides](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/).

In there they use a ResourceDictionary bound to ContentPage.Resources. I have tried to mimic this and after compiling fine the application starts up and gives me back a NullReferenceException.

I have tried to add the dictionary to the Grid.Resources and I get the same exception.

I use Xamarin.Forms v2.3.1.114 together with Prism.Forms v6.2 I do not know which of these is causing the issue, or if it is caused by something else all together.

Here's my XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
         prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
         x:Class="BetulaApp.Views.MainPage"
         Title="MainPage">

  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <Style x:Key="TitleStyle" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,20,0,20" />
      </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>

  <Grid>
    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
       Style="{StaticResource TitleStyle}" />
  </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

Any help with this matter would be awesome!

[E1] Added Exception Info:

[image: Exception Message]

**CallStack** Is not in a loaded module.
    [External Code]

> 0x95 in Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.Platform.LayoutRootPage at C:\BuildAgent\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\Platform.cs:279,5   C#
>
> 0x12 in Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.Platform.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IPlatformLayout.OnLayout at C:\BuildAgent\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\Platform.cs:196,5  C#
>
> 0x20 in Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PlatformRenderer.OnLayout at C:\BuildAgent\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\PlatformRenderer.cs:73,4  C#
>
> 0x12 in Android.Views.ViewGroup.n_OnLayout_ZIIII at /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.Views.ViewGroup.cs:3427,4  C#

Comment: can you add your exception?

Comment: @Rohit Sorry, I should have done it staight away.

Comment: Its too hard to read from the image, will it be okay to add the stack too?

Comment: @Rohit The call stack was not loaded in a module so this is the best I can give you. It's a direct copy of my CallStack window.

Comment: try removing the margin property in the setter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @nishantvodoo for suggesting removing the setter. 
I messed around and was the 'VerticalAlignment' setter that caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Forms does not have `VerticalAlignment` property for `View`, try `VerticalOptions` instead.